# Pyramid: How to autogenerate sitemap?

Tags: python, pyramid, sitemap

Is there a way to generate sitemaps on the fly and regularly submit them to Google using Pyramid?

I've seen 2 code snippets ([here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/108/) and [here](http://www.seedsmention.cloudysunny14.org/show_mention?id=ag9zfmxha3NobWljbGllbnRyEAsSCE1lbnRpb25zGNGMAQw)) for doing this in Flask, but they don't seem applicable to Pyramid.

Specifically, when I include `config.add_route('sitemap', '/sitemap.xml')` in `__init__.py` and then the following view:

```
@view_config(route_name='sitemap', renderer='static/sitemap.xml')
def sitemap(request):
    ingredients = [ ingredient.name for ingredient in Cosmeceutical.get_all() ]
    products = [ product.name for product in Product.get_all() ]
    return dict(ingredients=ingredients, products=products)
```

I get an error:

```
File "/home/home/SkinResearch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4.5-    py2.7.egg/pyramid/registry.py", line 148, in _get_intrs_by_pairs
raise KeyError((category_name, discriminator))
KeyError: ('renderer factories', '.xml')
```

Changing the view to:

```
@view_config(route_name='sitemap', renderer='static/sitemap.xml.jinja2')
def sitemap(request):
    ingredients = [ ingredient.name for ingredient in Cosmeceutical.get_all() ]
    products = [ product.name for product in Product.get_all() ]
    request.response.content_type = 'text/xml'
    return dict(ingredients=ingredients, products=products)
```

Gets past the KeyError from before, but gives me a 404 when I try navigating to `mysite.com/static/sitemap.xml.` What's going on?

EDIT: This is my sitemap.jinja2 file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

{% for page in other_pages %}
<url>
  <loc>http://www.wisderm.com/{{page}}</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
{% endfor %}

{% for ingredient in ingredients %}
<url>
  <loc>http://www.wisderm.com/ingredients/{{ingredient.replace(' ', '+')}}</loc>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
{% endfor %}

{% for product in products %}
<url>
  <loc>http://www.wisderm.com/products/{{product.replace(' ', '+')}}</loc>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
{% endfor %}

</urlset>
```

Comment: In addition to what @SachaGottfried said, I think that it is a bit strange to see a template in `static/` directory - the latter is usually is configured to serve _static files_ - I'm wondering if you're accidentally allowing your templates' sources to be downloaded. Try accessing `http://mysite.tld/static/sitemap.xml.jinja2` and see if you can access the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to establish http://example.com/sitemap.xml as your sitemap URL do that.

Add this line to **init**.py to register URL pattern http://example.com/sitemap.xml as route `sitemap`

```
config.add_route('sitemap', '/sitemap.xml')
```

register view code for route `sitemap` and render response with your custom jinja2 template  `sitemap.jinja2`. The file extension `jinja2' will trigger usage of jinja2 renderer.

```
@view_config(route_name='sitemap', renderer='static/sitemap.jinja2')
def sitemap(request):
    ingredients = [ ingredient.name for ingredient in Cosmeceutical.get_all() ]
    products = [ product.name for product in Product.get_all() ]
    return dict(ingredients=ingredients, products=products)
```

This will fix your errors resulting from trying to name your templates like URLs. But that mixed up renderer conventions shown below.

- *.pt triggers Chameleon renderer
- *.jinja2 triggers Jinja2 renderer
- *.mako triggers Mako renderer
- *.xml triggers XML renderer (that raised your first error)

Now it is still up to you to create XML based on [sitemaps protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/de/protocol.html). But your code looks promising. You pass your resource tree to the XML template. Every resource usually has access to their properties like URL or last_changed stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html?highlight=get_current_registry#pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_registry)

```
from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry

def mview(request):
    reg = get_current_registy
```

when I look into source there is method `get_routes_mapper` in `pyramid.config.Configurator`.

Maybe it helps You to generate sitemap on the 'fly' :)

Comment: Registered routes do not tell the whole story about the resource tree of an application. Registered routes will not change during the application runtime of pyramid application but the resource tree usually changes when users can do CRUD stuff on content. These changes are subject of sitemaps submission to Google and search engines.